# Problem with jquery setting wrong RequestUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the $ajax interface, working from localhost.

First example works as expected, RequestUrl (seen e.g. in Chrome Developer tools network tab) is: /commentSubmitted

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/commentSubmitted',
        data: "hi"});
```

This here doesn't work as expected, it appends the current browser url (referrer) to it:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'anyotherstring/commentSubmitted',
        data: "hi"});
```

I would like to have the RequestUrl always be the exact string I specify. For some reason the RequestUrl looks like this: `/nested/url/I/dont/care/about/anyotherstring/commentSubmitted`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example, due to the nature of relative URLs, appends "anyotherstring/commentSubmitted" to wherever you are now. So if you're at "/nested/url/I/dont/care/about/", that's where the POST request would go.

Instead, begin with a "/" to specify an absolute path.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Accept the answer if your question has been answered, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash.

```
url: '/anyotherstring/commentSubmitted',
```

The first example begins width slash, which means "strip old address and put this one right behind the domain name". In the second example, you are using a relative address, which is always appended at the end of current URL. 
It is similar to if you put it into href or src attribute.